# Как показать таблицу при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при одинарном нажатии оставалась таблица, а не при зажиме?

```css
ul.nav li:active>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">фильтр</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Для таких вещей `JS` придумали

Comment: здраствуйте, я не знаю как это реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Во-первых, никогда не вещай обработчик событий на ссылку... Тег `<a href="#">фильтр</a>`, внедрили  в `html`, для того, чтобы она была ссылкой... Ссылка должна оставаться ссылкой...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, поможет в решении этой проблемы - `focus`:

```css
CSS .nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.down-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .2s ease
}

.btn:focus+.down-menu {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="btn" href="#">фильтр</a>
    <ul class="down-menu">
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: И какую роль тут играет  `pointer-events`???????

Comment: Ошибся, совсем не то написал

Comment: большое спасибо всем и удачи)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('.li').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
document.querySelector('.ul').classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
.ul.active {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="li">фильтр
    <ul class="ul">
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```